# How can I create a regex from a list of words?

Tags: python, regex, validation, cpu-word

I have a dict of words (actually I have nested dicts of verb conjugations, but that isn't relevant) and I want to make a regex by combining them.

```
{
  'yo': 'hablaba',
  'tú': 'hablabas',
  'él': 'hablaba',
  'nosotros': 'hablábamos',
  'vosotros': 'hablabais',
  'ellos': 'hablaban',
  'vos': 'hablabas',
}
```

... to make:

```
'habl((aba(s|is|n)?)|ábamos)' # I think that's right
```

If I don't include `'hablábamos'` it's easy - they're all the same prefix, and I can get:

```
'hablaba(s|is|n)?'
```

... but I want a general form. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you trying to *generate* a regular expression from the values in the dictionary? Or are you trying to write a regular expression to *validate* the values in the dictionary. Or something else entirely?

Comment: I want to generate it. Is my tag wrong?

Comment: There is a JavaScript library that will do this for you: https://github.com/devongovett/regexgen (maybe Python has something similar?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is possible.

To get you started, this is how I would break down the problem.

Calculate the root by finding the longest possible string that matches the start of all of the declined values:

```
>>> root = ''
>>> for c in hablar['yo']:
...     if all(v.startswith(root + c) for v in hablar.itervalues()):
...         root += c
...     else:
...        break
... 
>>> root
'habl'
```

Whatever's left of the words makes a `list` of endings.

```
>>> endings = [v[len(root):] for v in hablar.itervalues()]
>>> print endings
['abas', 'aba', 'abais', 'aba', '\xc3\xa1bamos', 'aban', 'abas']
```

You may then want to weed out the duplicates:

```
>>> unique_endings = set(endings)
>>> print unique_endings
set(['abas', 'abais', '\xc3\xa1bamos', 'aban', 'aba'])
```

Then join these endings together with pipes:

```
>>> conjoined_endings = '|'.join(unique_endings)
>>> print conjoined_endings
abas|abais|ábamos|aban|aba
```

Forming the regular expression is a simple matter combining the root and the conjoined_endings string in parentheses:

```
>>> final_regex = '{}({})'.format(root, conjoined_endings)
>>> print final_regex
habl(abas|abais|ábamos|aban|aba)
```

Comment: Thank you @Johnsyweb, yes that helps. But I cant vote you up :( "requires 15 reputation". Shall I accept you?

Comment: @MalenaTorres: you're welcome. Hopefully this will get you started even if my linguistic terms are off. I'm curious as to why you want to compress the regular expressions so much, you're not dealing with large amount of data and more complex expressions are only going to add to your validation times.

Comment: I made my example more simple than it is, really it will be like `{'yo': '\w+aba'}`, &c. Finally I want to compare irregular verbs to regular for their rules, and I will have another dict like `yo = {'imperfecto': '\w+aba', 'presente': '\w+o'}`. More complicated for irregular verbs though, now I am just starting out with my idea to see what I can do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to have a less clever approach

```
>>> x={
...   'yo': 'hablaba',
...   'tú': 'hablabas',
...   'él': 'hablaba',
...   'nosotros': 'hablábamos',
...   'vosotros': 'hablabais',
...   'ellos': 'hablaban',
...   'vos': 'hablabas',
... }
>>> x
{'t\xc3\xba': 'hablabas', 'yo': 'hablaba', 'vosotros': 'hablabais', '\xc3\xa9l': 'hablaba', 'nosotros': 'habl\xc3\xa1bamos', 'ellos': 'hablaban', 'vos': 'hablabas'}
>>> x.values
<built-in method values of dict object at 0x20e6490>
>>> x.values()
['hablabas', 'hablaba', 'hablabais', 'hablaba', 'habl\xc3\xa1bamos', 'hablaban', 'hablabas']
>>> "|".join(x.values())
'hablabas|hablaba|hablabais|hablaba|habl\xc3\xa1bamos|hablaban|hablabas'
```

If you just join the hash values with an alternation operator then it should do what you want

Comment: Thank you Vorsprung :) But I have lots of words and other conjugations (that one I gave is imperfect conjugation, there are about 15 more) and I dont want to use too much space. But yes your idea works :)

Comment: I always think that computer memory is cheaper than my valuable time :)

Comment: There is certainly a lot to be said for keeping it simple!

Comment: @MalenaTorres: please add that motivating detail to the original question statement above. It makes a difference. Also, do you really want the regex with the fewest chars? (or just a fairly optimal '|'-separated concatenated list taking advantage of shared prefixes?)